# RVM autolibs for rubies in production environments

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

In production, once I was used to add some utility packages (like curl, ssl etc.) to the RVM distribution *before* installing rubies, just to be sure that no missing libs requirements warning or errors would be generated from the hosted applications.

Now RVM deprecated pkg and switched to autolibs, documentation [explains](https://rvm.io/packages):

```
rvm autolibs enable
```

How does this relate with packages? Do you still need to manually add packages such as ssl or everything is already working fine automatically with no surprises?

My version of RVM is 1.20.13 (stable)

**EDIT**: I tried directly and discovered that rvm autolibs enable is enough to accomplish the purpose of adding all the libraries needed by rubies, but eventual further discussion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried directly and discovered that rvm autolibs enable is enough to accomplish the purpose of adding all the libraries needed by rubies.